# Using Apache Commons CSV to read file starting from the second line

Tags: java, apache, file, csv

I have this `CSV` file that I want to read:

```
ID;Name;Age
GEORGE;GEORGE;19
JOHN;JOHNNY;45
MARCO;MARCO POLO;32
```

I also have to read it using this command:

```
for (CSVRecord rec : CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(';').parse(in)) {
    //some code
}
```

I don't want to read the first line, because it's just the description of what contain the fields

I also tried to find the resolution of this in `stackoverflow` and other sites, but I didn't find how to do it.

EDIT 1: I imported `CSVRecord` and `CSVFormat` from `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat` and `org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord`

EDIT 2: My post is not a duplicate because I'm asking about a library, just as @slim commented

Comment: What is that `CSVRecord`, and `CSVFormat`? You have to show us more of what you have.

Comment: @E_net4 sorry, I edited my question, now you can know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip first line while reading CSV file in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306270/skip-first-line-while-reading-csv-file-in-java)

Comment: Please tell us which CSV library do you use.

Comment: Probably use `CSVFormat#withSkipHeaderRecord(true)`

Comment: @YMomb - not really a dupe. This post is asking about a library. The other is rolling their own parser.

Comment: @slim yes! thanks for understand it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "Working with headers" section of the [user guide](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html).

Specifically, you can configure the parser to know that the first line is a header, using `CSVFormat.withFirstRowAsHeader()`

Answer (score 1):

There are many stackoverflow resources for this question.
[Skip first line while reading CSV file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18306270/skip-first-line-while-reading-csv-file-in-java) seems like the best resource for your answer.

Comment: Also, if you are interested in only using CSVRecord, the [solution](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/apache/commons/csv-commons/writeread-csv-files-with-apache-commons-csv-example/) provided for 'Read from CSV File' would do the trick!